# .Net: DateRange cannot be converted to type 'Date

Tags: .net

[link text](http://forums.asp.net/p/714292/714628.aspx#714628)

I'm having the same problem. My date format is MM/dd/yyyy. How do i find out the date format in my system and change it with code.

Comment: You really should include the text for the question on this site as well since your linked thread could disappear and then this thread would be useless since in the future if anyone read it they would not know what you were referring to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set proper culture for a [current thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentculture.aspx). DateTime.Parse uses date settings from culture of current thread (btw, [I love you, Reflector!](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/)):

```
public static DateTime Parse(string s)
{
    return DateTimeParse.Parse(s, DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo, DateTimeStyles.None);
}
```

where "DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo" is:

```
public static DateTimeFormatInfo CurrentInfo
{
    get
    {
        CultureInfo currentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
        if (!currentCulture.m_isInherited)
        {
            DateTimeFormatInfo dateTimeInfo = currentCulture.dateTimeInfo;
            if (dateTimeInfo != null)
            {
                return dateTimeInfo;
            }
        }
        return (DateTimeFormatInfo) currentCulture.GetFormat(typeof(DateTimeFormatInfo));
    }
}
```

There are a lot of how-to about globalisation, just try to search them ( [example of such how-to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx) :))

Answer (score 0):

If its a date object then you just need to format it using the ToString method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tostring.aspx

Code Sample:

```
using System;

public class DateToStringExample
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      DateTime dateValue = new DateTime(2008, 6, 15, 21, 15, 07);
      // Create an array of standard format strings.
      string[] standardFmts = {"d", "D", "f", "F", "g", "G", "m", "o", 
                               "R", "s", "t", "T", "u", "U", "y"};
      // Output date and time using each standard format string.
      foreach (string standardFmt in standardFmts)
         Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", standardFmt, 
                           dateValue.ToString(standardFmt));
      Console.WriteLine();

      // Create an array of some custom format strings.
      string[] customFmts = {"h:mm:ss.ff t", "d MMM yyyy", "HH:mm:ss.f", 
                             "dd MMM HH:mm:ss", @"\Mon\t\h\: M", "HH:mm:ss.ffffzzz" };
      // Output date and time using each custom format string.
      foreach (string customFmt in customFmts)
         Console.WriteLine("'{0}': {1}", customFmt,
                           dateValue.ToString(customFmt));
   }
}
// This example displays the following output to the console:
//       d: 6/15/2008
//       D: Sunday, June 15, 2008
//       f: Sunday, June 15, 2008 9:15 PM
//       F: Sunday, June 15, 2008 9:15:07 PM
//       g: 6/15/2008 9:15 PM
//       G: 6/15/2008 9:15:07 PM
//       m: June 15
//       o: 2008-06-15T21:15:07.0000000
//       R: Sun, 15 Jun 2008 21:15:07 GMT
//       s: 2008-06-15T21:15:07
//       t: 9:15 PM
//       T: 9:15:07 PM
//       u: 2008-06-15 21:15:07Z
//       U: Monday, June 16, 2008 4:15:07 AM
//       y: June, 2008
//       
//       'h:mm:ss.ff t': 9:15:07.00 P
//       'd MMM yyyy': 15 Jun 2008
//       'HH:mm:ss.f': 21:15:07.0
//       'dd MMM HH:mm:ss': 15 Jun 21:15:07
//       '\Mon\t\h\: M': Month: 6
//       'HH:mm:ss.ffffzzz': 21:15:07.0000-07:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your assigning the date in the aspx file and expecting the format to be mm/dd/yyyy when it is probably dd/mm/yyyy so it is blowing up.  Are you deploying to a system that uses a different date format?

If so, maybe add the ranges through code manually and assign them using the expected format which is expecting a date object.

Eg.

```
YourDateValidator.MaximumValue = YourMaxDateTimeObject;
YourDateValidator.MinimumValue = YourMinDateTimeObject;
```

Comment: @Jack if this answer or another helped you, you should set an accepted answer so that others reading this question can locate the solution that helped you.